# Cannot resolve import "MultiLabelBinarizer"

Tags: scikit-learn

I am new to the "scikit-Learn" API and wish to implement a multilabel classification problem. After importing the following packages:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
```

I get an error which says 'Unresolved import: MultiLabelBinarizer'. But other related packages imported seem to work fine. I wonder why the 'MultiLabelBinarizer' cannot be imported, given the fact that the 'sklearn ' package was properly installed. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the reason, in case someone comes across the same problem. The error was due to fact that I was running the above code on 'sklearn' version 0.14 (which was installed by default on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS) instead of 0.16. I also think the MultiLabelBinarizer Class is only available on  'sklearn' version 0.16 (I have not tried the 0.15 - in case there is any).